# Do the List iterators support remove?

Tags: java, list, iterator

The remove method is optional in [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and ListIterator. Do the Iterators or ListIterators you get from the JDK lists implement the `remove` operation? This is not stated in the documentation.

Comment: Some iterators from the standard library support remove. Some do not. (The Java `Iterator` interface is arguably broken in this respect.)

Comment: @khelwood I'm specifically asking about the iterators you get from Lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In summary:

- ArrayList.iterator supports `remove` even though it's not explicitly documented
- LinkedList.iterator supports `remove` even though it's not explicitly documented
- [CopyOnWriteArrayList.iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#iterator--) does **not** support `remove`
- List returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList` does **not** support `remove`

The rule of thumb for the standard classes seems to be: iterators support removal unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's kind of interesting to answer. Java has a history behind **Iterators**. Let me tell you the history, Then, it'll be clear why things are like this.

Before **Iterators** java has **Enumeration** Interface. The methods **Enumeration** provided are:

1. boolean hasMoreElements()
2. Object nextElement()

Now, java legacy classes like **Vector** supports Enumeration.

But then, **Enumeration** got banned in Java while Java started writing its **Collection** framework in a totally new way i.e. to modernize its **Collection** framework. Now, in the new **Collections** java used **Iterators**. These iterators support the following mehtods:

1. boolean hasNext()
2. E next()
3. default void remove()
4. default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action)

I think I've made myself clear to this point.

Now, think about java totally started using **Iterators**, but there is still a lot of legacy code out there with **Enumerations**. So, the question is what will happen with those code, as java got updated?

So, java has provided you with a opportunity to use **Iterators** over **Enumerations** by default with some legacy classes and those **Iterators** of those legacy classes are just a wrapper around **Enumeration** Interface. But these **Iterators** does not support **remove()** cause those classes underline **Enumeration** Interface does not support **remove()**, that's why. So, when you call **remove()** on those **Iterators**, it throws **UnsupportedOperationException** -> this exception.

I hope till this everything is clear and you've got ur answer. But let me allow to say a little more.

What about those legacy classes those already have been written using **Enumerations**?

You can solve this problem as java has already done for itself, just provide **Iterator** wrapper over the **Enumeration** Interface for new codes you are writing. In this way, you will be writing new codes in new java features and you don't have to change the old code too :D

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does state that the default implementation of Iterator does not support [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--). Whether or not the `List#iterator` supports `remove` depends on the List implementation. For example, `ListItr` defined in the `ArrayList` implementation supports remove.